# How to use Onclick event when using <include> tag

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two **java class** and **two layout** for both the class.
Each **layout** is having one **button** in it.
Both classes are extending `Activity`.
Now in first layout I used **include** tag like this

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/clicked" 
    layout="@layout/activity_main" />
```

I can now see **two buttons** but the **second button** is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First** You have to declare and initialise the **include** view and then decalre and initialise both buttons using **view.findViewById()** method as follows:

```
View includeView = (View)findViewById(R.id.clicked);
Button button1 = (Button)includeView.findViewById(R.id.button1ID); //decalre button like this
Button button2 = (Button)includeView.findViewById(R.id.button2ID);
```

And then set their **onClickListeners**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //code whatever you want to do here
            }
        });

 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //code whatever you want to do here
            }
        });
```

** EDIT **

Fixed the typo. Should be **includeView** on the **findViewById**.
Good explanation though!

Comment: I already defined the onclickListener in their respected class.

Comment: have you done the same what i have suggested you here??? have you declared the **include** view

Comment: yes,I declared the include view.It says includeview is never used.

Comment: You are not using **include view** for defining your buttons. check my code again. I am defining button using **includeView.findViewById()**. Thats why your getting warning message includeview is never used.